# Export 3D data from PostGIS to any common open and standardized 3D file format

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, 3d-model

I am mainly curious, because I found this function: [`ST_AsX3D()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsX3D.html) in the list of PostGIS 3.2 "ST_As{*something*}" functions:

> st_asbinary, st_asbinary, st_asbinary, st_asbinary,
> st_asencodedpolyline, st_asewkb, st_asewkb, st_asewkt, st_asewkt,
> st_asewkt, st_asewkt, st_asewkt, st_asgeobuf, st_asgeobuf,
> st_asgeojson, st_asgeojson, st_asgeojson, st_asgeojson, st_asgml,
> st_asgml, st_asgml, st_asgml, st_asgml, st_ashexewkb, st_ashexewkb,
> st_askml, st_askml, st_askml, st_aslatlontext, st_asmvt, st_asmvt,
> st_asmvt, st_asmvt, st_asmvt, st_asmvtgeom, st_assvg, st_assvg,
> st_assvg, st_astext, st_astext, st_astext, st_astext, st_astext,
> st_astwkb, st_astwkb, st_asx3d

which can output the result of a query to an [`.x3d`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D) file:

[image: The Eiger mountain as an X3D file]
*Fig.1: The [Eiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiger) mountain as an X3D file. Dumped from many PostGIS PolygonZ.*

And I'm wondering: why does this particular function (`ST_AsX3D()`) exist / has been developed at some point in the PostGIS development, and not other such as for example: `ST_AsglTF()` or `ST_AsOBJ()` or any other 3D file format which is

1. open and documented as such
2. recognized as a standard in the field of 3D
   ?

Also, in case you know any custom pg function that can actually dump PostGIS 3D data to any one of such format, I would be glad to ear about it.

Comment: PostGIS is open source. Obviously some developer was paid for making  ST_AsX3D or had some own interest to do so.

Comment: The function seems to be created by Regina Obe quite a long time ago.